# Syntax for copying data into a new location on disk

Tags: c++

How would I copy the value new_id to a different memory address so that the 10 `new_id` integers all point to *different* places in memory?

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){

    int id = 0;

    for (int i=0 ; i < 10; ++i){
        int new_id = id;
        std::cout << id << " " << new_id << std::endl;
        std::cout << &id << " " << &new_id << std::endl;
        id += 1;
    }
    return 0;
};
```

Current result:

```
0 0
0x7ffced46f0a4 0x7ffced46f0a8
1 1
0x7ffced46f0a4 0x7ffced46f0a8
...
...
```

Desired result:

```
0 0
0x7ffced46f0a4 0x7ffced46f0a8
1 1
0x7ffced46f0a4 0x7ffced46f0a9
2 2
0x7ffced46f0a4 0x7ffced46f0a10
...
...
```

Comment: The address won't change just because you incremented the variable's value

Comment: Yes, but how would I make it change?

Comment: These are memory addresses, not locations on disk. If you want the integers to have different memory addresses, you can assign them to different variables. As it is, you're overwriting the same variable, and that variable keeps on having the same address in memory even if its overwritten.

Comment: Honestly, it looks to me like you want an int array of length 10 with each of the numbers at consecutive indices in the array.

Comment: Apologies, I ment in memory.

Comment: How about array of 10 integers `int new_id[10]` which has different address locations for each integer.

Comment: I need to dynamically create unique integers (as IDs) to pass to a bunch of objects I'm instantiating. At the moment they all point to the same variable in memory.

Comment: @SunilBojanapally Yes, this would work - however, these will be ID's so I wanted to use the increment pattern to ensure uniqueness when I modify the object in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the question asker's comment:

> I need to dynamically create unique integers (as IDs) to pass to a bunch of objects I'm instantiating. At the moment they all point to the same variable in memory

I think what they need are [UUIDs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/libs/uuid/uuid.html) rather than memory locations. Try using this library, it allows you to create unique identifiers that you can use to identify your objects, rather than using arbitrary memory locations to do so.